# How to get server-send events to work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML document and a server-side PHP script that I am trying to get to perform a server-send event with. But it just does not work -- nothing happens on page load.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>my title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script>
  function BlockElasticScroll(event) {
    event.preventDefault() ;
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body ontouchmove="BlockElasticScroll(event);">
  <h1>My Header</h1>
  <h2>Sub-Heading</h2>
  <div id="pool">250.00</div><div id="non-compat">Sorry but your phone will not work with this app.</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //check for browser support
    if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
      //create an object, passing it the name and location of the server side script
      var source = new EventSource('php/send_sse.php');
      //detect message receipt
      source.onmessage = function(event) {
        //write the received data to the page
        document.getElementById('pool').innerHTML = event.data;
      };
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('pool').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('non-compat').style.display = 'block';
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Script (send_sse.php -- works when I render it in a web browser)**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
echo "data: 500.00";
flush();
?>
```

**Some of my troubleshooting**

I put a hook into my PHP script to fire off a mail message back to myself. I received the email so I know the HTML doc & javascript is successfully calling the PHP script. For some reason, the PHP script does not call back to the HTML doc.

Comment: aren't events line-based? You haven't included a newline `\n`, so technically your event message isn't complete, therefore it won't be sent.

Comment: awesome @MarcB...that was the solution! Thanks - greatly appreciate your help. Technically I needed `\n\n` -- 2 of them